# C# Preventing excel from automtically changing my numbers to date

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently trying to convert XLS files into CSV files using C# without using any excel library. I have managed to convert it from XLS to CSV but I am currently facing a problem where the row which contains numbers is being automatically converted into a datetime format as the first cell above is a datetime. I cannot change the format of the original file.

Here is my code use for conversion of xls to csv:

```
protected static void convertExcelToCsv(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {

        int worksheetNumber = 1;

        var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", inputFile);
        var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);

        var dt = new DataTable();

        cnn.Open();
        var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
        string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", worksheet);
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);



        da.Fill(dt);

        cnn.Close();

        using (var wtr = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {


                bool firstLine = true;
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (!firstLine) { wtr.Write(","); } else { firstLine = false; }
                    var data = row[col.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", "");
                    wtr.Write(data);
                }
                wtr.WriteLine();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: If there is another way to convert xls to csv without using any excel library as reference please do share too! It might help solve my problem!

Comment: If you know how you want to read the values, then construct the Select statement to enforce the returned data type.  i.e. "Select [F1], CDbl([F2]) From Sheet1$" will force the second column to be converted to type Double.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

In IMEX mode, the driver looks at the first few rows (8 by default) to determine the format of the column. If the column is "intermixed," it defaults to text. It sounds like the non-date data don't appear until lower down in the file.

### Solution #1

You can increase the number of rows that it looks ahead by modifying the registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows`

### Solution #2

If you wind up with a `DateTime` and you wish to convert it to the integer value, you can use

```
readonly DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(1899,12,31);  //This is constant

var d = /* DateTime from Excel */
int originalValue = d.Subtract(baseDate).TotalDays;
```

### Solution #3

Ditch the driver. Use [Excel interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=vs.140).aspx) instead. Then you can read the underlying cell values, the formatted values, or whatever you want.

Comment: Hi John Wu, I am not able to use the Solution 1 as I am running the program in a server. I tested Solution 2 but the converted integer are different from the original number. For example, 04/05/1900 00:00 converts into 124 whereas it supposed to be 125. However for dates like 16/01/1900 00:00 it converts correctly into 16. As for solution 3 I cannot use it as it requires excel in the server if I am correct. As I tested the excel interop to convert it into csv the previous time but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem to me! As I didn't know what was the problem! Sadly my non date data only appears on the 12th row. :(

Comment: For your Solution 2, I suggest using [DateTime.FromOADate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx).  Of course this presumes the 1900 date system for Excel and not the 1904 system.

Comment: Do you know how to reverse it to find the number instead?

Comment: Probably with `DateTime.ToOADate`.